# How to store XML data list in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Im working on a script that will allow me to save the xml data in a table. This will be used to compare with other tables which also contains an xml data.
I've been successful so far for simple node tags, but have encountered an issue when trying to store the data from a list.

The XML data looks like this:[Sample XML Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lY2ak.png)

And my query is this:
[XML Query display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trkkz.png)

I am able to get the 'TypeCode' as the main node but for the value, it's always showing blank. I'm not sure how to handle the list in XML.

I'm thinking as long as I can save the data
''
'' as text in the Value column, then I can find another way to parse it and display it in a nicer way as another query.

Any help is appreciated :D Thanks!

Comment: sharing desired result will help more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your next question: Please do not post pictures. I had to type this in... Please provide consumable data, best as a *stand-alone* example to reproduce your issue.

```sql
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<Codes>
<TypeCodes type="list">
<item key="A" text="A1"/>
<item key="C" text="C1"/>
</TypeCodes>
</Codes>';

--the Xml "as is" 
SELECT @xml;

--fetch one value with XQuery
SELECT @xml.value('(/Codes/TypeCodes/item[@key="A"]/@text)[1]','varchar(10)');

--fetch all items as list
SELECT @xml.value('(/Codes/TypeCodes/@type)[1]','varchar(10)') AS TypeCode_type
      ,i.value('@key','varchar(10)') AS item_key
      ,i.value('@text','varchar(10)') AS item_text
FROM @xml.nodes('/Codes/TypeCodes/item') A(i);
```

check it out

Comment: Criss Was the question "`How to store XML data list in a table`" or "`how to get the data from the XML`"?

Comment: THanks Shnugo that worked :D apologies for the image, I'll make sure to type the data nxt time

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

SQL Server include special data type XML which is what you should use in order to store your XML data.

```
declare @MyXML XML = '
<codes>
    <Type>
        <Item key="1" />
    </Type>
</codes>
'
select @MyXML
```

Here is example of using table:

```
DROP TABLE IF eXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T(MyXML XML)
GO
INSERT T(MyXML) values ('
<codes>
    <Type>
        <Item key="1" />
    </Type>
</codes>
')
SELECT * FROM T
GO
```

For more information check this documentation:
[XML Data Type and Columns (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-type-and-columns-sql-server)